# How to restore/recover accidentally deleted key from google Authenticator?

Tags: security, google-authenticator

Is there any way to recover my accidentally deleted key from google authenticator app ? My android device is not rooted and am not able to access the 'com.google.android.apps.authenticator2' package. I have already tried adb pull/ adb backup but it is not usefull for non rooted device. Is there any way I can access to the database folder without root or rooting is the only option. Also I am not sure key will be there on the DB if I have manually deleted the key. Can anyone confirm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By deletion of key, if you mean to say that you've deleted your account from Google authenticator app, you'll not be able to recover it by adb systems.

Simply go to Google my account, log in, and if it asks for authenticator pass code, choose a different methods of verification, and then either backup codes or through mobile verification (whichever you've got active). Then switch off authenticator system of verification. Again switch it on, and follow on-screen processes. Done. This is the simplest method to regain authenticator access.

Comment: I was using authentication for non-google sites and their support team is not responding. So as an alternate solution, I was trying to access the database folder of the app. But it was not possible without root. As per your answer, I will not be able to recover it in any case.

Comment: Can't you disable the authentication and then enable it again? Are there no other systems of accessing your account on those sites? If so, disable and then again enable the authentication.

Comment: When I try to login into my account it ask for token after entering the password and I don't have that token(which is generated by that authenticator app). I have tried almost all the possible solution availablefor unrooted devices  on google/youtube. Now looking for expert advice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot recover your secret keys in your Google Authenticator app.  If you haven’t saved the QR codes or secret keys, you should contact the support team of service which you protect with Google Authenticator and they will help you to restore the access to your account. After this, you will be able to issue a new token. In order to avoid reoccurrence, you can use hardware tokens.

Comment: Even if there's disclosure, this looks really spammy...

Comment: What if I have adb backup of the app ? Will that work ?

Comment: As I know it won't work (for devices without root access)